# Migration from Cloudformation to serverless framework

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I try to change infrastructure manager for lambdas from native cloudformation to serverless framework, but I have several resources, which manages by cloudformation stack and new stack, which created by serverless tries to create new resources but I don't want it and even more this causes deployment fail

**serverless.yml**

```yaml
service: projectName-images
frameworkVersion: '3'
configValidationMode: error

provider:
  name: aws
  deploymentMethod: direct
  region: ${env:AWS_DEFAULT_REGION, env:AWS_REGION, 'eu-west-1'}
  runtime: nodejs16.x
  tags:
    managedBy: 'Serverless Framework'

functions:
  ResizeImage:
    name: resizeImage
    handler: src/handlers/resize-image.handler
    role: ${cf:images.ResizeImageLambdaRole}
    memorySize: 1769
    timeout: 12
    package:
      patterns:
        - '!**'
        - src/**
        - node_modules/**
        - '!src/raw-identify'
        - '!src/simple_dcraw'
        - '!src/dcraw'
      individually: true

resources:
  Parameters:
    DomainZoneId:
      Description: The Hosted Zone ID for the domain.
      Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>
      Default: /projectName/zone
    Domain:
      Description: The domain name
      Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>
      Default: /projectName/domain
    DomainCertificate:
      Description: The SSL certificate ARN for the subdomain.
      Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>
      Default: /projectName/domain/certificate
    FilesCertificate:
      Description: The SSL certificate ARN for the subdomain.
      Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>
      Default: /projectName/files/certificate
    FilesDeleteAfterDays:
      Description: Number of days until a file is deleted in files S3.
      Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>
      Default: /projectName/files/delete_after_days
    ResizedImagesDeleteAfterDays:
      Description: Number of days until a file is deleted in files S3.
      Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>
      Default: /projectName/images/delete_resized_after_days
    MskBootstrapServers:
      Description: The MSK bootstrap servers
      Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>
      Default: /projectName/msk/bootstrap_servers
    MskUsername:
      Description: The MSK SASL/SCRAM username.
      Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>
      Default: /projectName/msk/username
    MskPassword:
      Description: The MSK SASL/SCRAM password.
      Type: String
      Default: /projectName/msk/password
    SentryDsn:
      Description: Sentry DSN to connect lambdas with real time issues reporting
      Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>
      Default: /projectName/images_lambdas/sentry_dsn
    projectNameEnvironment:
      Description: projectName environment
      Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>
      Default: /projectName/environment
        
  Resources:
    ImagesDeadLetterQueue:
      Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
      Properties:
        QueueName: ImagesDLQ

    ImagesQueue:
      Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
      Properties:
        QueueName: ImagesQueue
        ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds: 20
        VisibilityTimeout: 12
        RedrivePolicy:
          deadLetterTargetArn: !GetAtt ImagesDeadLetterQueue.Arn
          maxReceiveCount: 5

    ImagesQueuePolicy:
      Type: AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy
      Properties:
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
            # S3 write permission
            - Effect: Allow
              Action: sqs:SendMessage
              Resource: '*'
              Principal:
                AWS: '*' # !GetAtt ImagesS3Bucket.Arn
            # convertImage lambda read permission
            - Effect: Allow
              Action: sqs:ReceiveMessage
              Resource: '*'
              Principal:
                AWS: '*' # !GetAtt ConvertImageLambda.Arn
        Queues:
          - !Ref ImagesQueue

    ImagesS3Bucket:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      DependsOn:
        - ImagesQueue
      Properties:
        BucketName:
          !Join ['-', ['images', !Join ['-', !Split ['.', !Ref Domain]]]]
        BucketEncryption:
          ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration:
            - ServerSideEncryptionByDefault:
                SSEAlgorithm: AES256
        CorsConfiguration:
          CorsRules:
            - AllowedMethods:
                - HEAD
                - GET
                - PUT
                - POST
              AllowedOrigins:
                - '*'
              AllowedHeaders:
                - '*'
              ExposedHeaders:
                - Connection
                - Server
                - Date
        PublicAccessBlockConfiguration:
          BlockPublicAcls: true
          BlockPublicPolicy: true
          IgnorePublicAcls: true
          RestrictPublicBuckets: true
        LifecycleConfiguration:
          Rules:
            - Id: DeleteResizedAfterExpirationDays
              Status: Enabled
              ExpirationInDays: !Ref ResizedImagesDeleteAfterDays
              Prefix: 'resized/'
              NoncurrentVersionExpiration:
                NoncurrentDays: 1
        NotificationConfiguration:
          QueueConfigurations:
            - Event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
              Queue: !GetAtt ImagesQueue.Arn
              Filter:
                S3Key:
                  Rules:
                    - Name: prefix
                      Value: original/
        VersioningConfiguration:
          Status: Enabled

    ResizeImageLambdaRole:
      Type: AWS::IAM::Role
      Properties:
        AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Principal:
                Service:
                  - lambda.amazonaws.com
              Action:
                - sts:AssumeRole
        Path: /
        ManagedPolicyArns:
          - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/CloudWatchLambdaInsightsExecutionRolePolicy
        Policies:
          - PolicyName: root
            PolicyDocument:
              Version: '2012-10-17'
              Statement:
                - Effect: Allow
                  Action:
                    - s3:GetObject
                    - s3:PutObject
                  Resource:
                    !Join [
                      '',
                      [
                        'arn:aws:s3:::images-',
                        !Join ['-', !Split ['.', !Ref Domain]],
                        '/*',
                      ],
                    ]
                - Effect: Allow
                  Action:
                    - logs:CreateLogGroup
                    - logs:CreateLogStream
                    - logs:PutLogEvents
                  Resource: 'arn:aws:logs:*:*:*'

    ImagesApi:
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
      Properties:
        Description: projectName Images API Gateway
        EndpointConfiguration:
          Types:
            - REGIONAL
        Name: images-api-gateway
        BinaryMediaTypes:
          - '*~1*'

    ImagesProxyResource:
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Resource
      Properties:
        RestApiId: !Ref ImagesApi
        ParentId: !GetAtt ImagesApi.RootResourceId
        PathPart: '{proxy+}'

    ApiGatewayRootMethod:
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
      Properties:
        AuthorizationType: NONE
        HttpMethod: ANY
        Integration:
          IntegrationHttpMethod: POST
          Type: AWS_PROXY
          IntegrationResponses:
            - StatusCode: 200
          Uri: !Sub
            - arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${lambdaArn}/invocations
            - lambdaArn: !GetAtt ResizeLambdaTestLambdaFunction.Arn
        ResourceId: !Ref ImagesProxyResource
        RestApiId: !Ref ImagesApi

    ApiGatewayDeployment:
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment
      DependsOn:
        - ApiGatewayRootMethod
      Properties:
        RestApiId: !Ref ImagesApi
        StageName: v1

    ResizeImageLambdaPermission:
      Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
      Properties:
        FunctionName: !Ref ResizeLambdaTestLambdaFunction
        Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
        Principal: apigateway.amazonaws.com
        SourceArn: !Sub arn:aws:execute-api:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:${ImagesApi}/*/*/*

    ImagesCloudFrontOAI:
      Type: AWS::CloudFront::CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity
      Properties:
        CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentityConfig:
          Comment: Access identity for ImagesS3Bucket

    ImagesCloudFrontDistribution:
      Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
      Properties:
        DistributionConfig:
          OriginGroups:
            Items:
              - Id: ImageFailoverGroup
                Members:
                  Items:
                    - OriginId: S3Origin
                    - OriginId: APIGatewayOrigin
                  Quantity: 2
                FailoverCriteria:
                  StatusCodes:
                    Items:
                      - 403 # S3 returns 403 when the image doesn't exist
                    Quantity: 1
            Quantity: 1
          Origins:
            - Id: S3Origin
              DomainName:
                !Join [
                  '',
                  [
                    'images-',
                    !Join ['-', !Split ['.', !Ref Domain]],
                    '.s3.amazonaws.com',
                  ],
                ]
              S3OriginConfig:
                OriginAccessIdentity:
                  !Join [
                    '',
                    [
                      'origin-access-identity/cloudfront/',
                      !Ref ImagesCloudFrontOAI,
                    ],
                  ]
            - Id: APIGatewayOrigin
              DomainName:
                !Join [
                  '.',
                  [
                    !Ref ImagesApi,
                    execute-api,
                    !Ref AWS::Region,
                    amazonaws.com,
                  ],
                ]
              OriginPath: /v1
              CustomOriginConfig:
                HTTPSPort: 443
                OriginProtocolPolicy: https-only
          DefaultCacheBehavior:
            DefaultTTL: 2592000
            MinTTL: 2592000 #30 days
            MaxTTL: 2592000
            TargetOriginId: ImageFailoverGroup
            ViewerProtocolPolicy: redirect-to-https
            AllowedMethods:
              - HEAD
              - GET
              - OPTIONS
            ForwardedValues:
              QueryString: false
              Headers:
                - Origin
                - Access-Control-Request-Headers
                - Access-Control-Request-Method
                - Sec-Fetch-Site
                - Sec-Fetch-Mode
              Cookies:
                Forward: none
          Aliases:
            - !Join ['', ['images.', !Ref Domain]]
          DefaultRootObject: index.html
          HttpVersion: http2
          ViewerCertificate:
            AcmCertificateArn: !Ref DomainCertificate
            SslSupportMethod: sni-only
            MinimumProtocolVersion: TLSv1.2_2021
          PriceClass: PriceClass_100
          Enabled: true

    ImagesCloudFrontDNS:
      Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup
      DependsOn:
        - ImagesCloudFrontDistribution
      Properties:
        HostedZoneId: !Ref DomainZoneId
        RecordSets:
          - Name: !Join ['', ['images.', !Ref Domain]]
            Type: A
            AliasTarget:
              HostedZoneId: Z2FDTNDATAQYW2
              DNSName: !GetAtt ImagesCloudFrontDistribution.DomainName

  Outputs:
    ImagesBucket:
      Value: !Ref ImagesS3Bucket
      Export:
        Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-images-bucket
    ImagesBucketName:
      Value: !GetAtt ImagesS3Bucket.DomainName
      Export:
        Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-images-bucket-domain-name
    ImagesCloudfrontOai:
      Value: !Ref ImagesCloudFrontOAI
      Export:
        Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-images-cloudfront-oai
```

Current configuration will fail with error `Resource handler returned message: "Resource of type 'AWS::SQS::Queue' with identifier 'ImagesDLQ' already exists."`

I tried use aws import feature(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-existing-stack.html) to import existing resources to serverless created stack, but it cause error `The following resource types are not supported for resource import: AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy,AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup,AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup,AWS::Lambda::Permission,AWS::Lambda::Permission`

I tried make deployment using existing stack, which currently uses for deploy lambdas

**serverless.yml**

```yaml
service: projectName-images
frameworkVersion: '3'
configValidationMode: error

provider:
  ...
  stackName: images

functions:
  ...

resources:
  Resources:
    ...
```

And I got `Could not parse CloudFormation template` error

Also I tried to find a way to not create resources if they already exists, eg use conditions(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/conditions-section-structure.html), but I don't have any parametrs based on which I can build condition

I also looked in this https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/3183 issue, and looks like serverless doesn't have this posibility, but is it real, that I don't have any solutions, except delete infrastructure and recreate it again?